# PrimeNG Accordion: Programmatically change header and content styles

Tags: css, angular, accordion, primeng

I've the following accordion group:

```
<p-accordion multiple=true>
    <p-accordionTab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" styleClass="{{tab.myClass}}" header="{{tab.header}}"
        [selected]="false">
        {{tab.description}}
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

It's usually populated dinamically by tabs size. The goal is to have different background and other styles, depending of tab content. So I have that myClass style variable which could change at each accordion tab creation. E.g. assuming to use myClass = 'myClass':

```
:host ::ng-deep .myClass.p-accordion {
    .p-accordion-header:not(.p-disabled).p-highlight .p-accordion-header-link {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Anyway I was not able to create a css rule to achieve this goal.
Can anyone assist?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was using a wrapper div of each accordion tab:

```
<p-accordion multiple=true>
    <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs" class="{{tab.customClass}}">
        <p-accordionTab header="{{tab.header}}"
            [selected]="false">
            {{tab.description}}
        </p-accordionTab>
    </div>
</p-accordion>
```

where :

```
.customClass * {
    background: red !important;
    //other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a different style for each tab you need to make it dependent on the tab. Right now you set the same style for each. One approach would be to create a pipe which provides the class name.

```
<p-accordionTab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" styleClass="{{tab | getTabClass}}" header="{{tab.header}}"
```

Comment: yes sorry i edited my question, that's exactly what I'm doing.
The problem is how to reach the content background from such an external class, since there are 5 or 6 level of html elements created on this primeng component.
Thanks.

Comment: I just wonder, according to the docs https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/accordion the tab has no `styleClass` property. Only the accordion itself hast

Comment: Noted. Any ideas to get rid of this problem?